# FBLikeControl callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

is there any way I can get some kind of feedback from the new FBLikeControl if the user liked the page? Or at least to know somehow, that he returned back to the app from the Facebook app?

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand the question. If/when the user returns to your app (from the FB app), your AppDelegate's application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method will be called. Since there's no other way to open an app (or go back) on iOS, this is how you know that the user has returned.

Comment: so there is no possibility to register myself as a delegate of the like control directly or supply the control with a callback block to notify me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Since Facebook apparently made this header private, you now have to subscribe directly to the notification using a raw string:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myObject selector:@selector(myCallback:) name:@"FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification"];
```

**Old answer for reference:**

For anyone in the future looking for this: I ended up subscribing myself to FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification notifications. Once the notification is received you can do the following:

```
if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[FBLikeActionController class]]) {
    if ([(FBLikeActionController*)notification.object objectIsLiked]) {
       // do your stuff here, user liked!
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse me, can you show me some resource on how to subscribe to `FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification` as in your answer because I can't find anything except some github link

Comment: simply do [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) name:FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
Also make sure to import #import <FacebookSDK/FBLikeActionController.h> and have the latest version of the SDK installed since the FBLikeControl class is quite new actually

Comment: This isn't working for me; FBLikeActionController appears to be a private header, not included with the API.

Comment: have you installed the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification is not a public property to access outside the SDK! Which version of SDK are you using @Tim

Comment: The correct signature is: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myObject selector:@selector(myCallback:) name:@"FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification" object:nil];`

Comment: FBLikeActionController is not import in new Fb sdk,then how can i get FBLikeActionController class?

Comment: Is this still working? I don't seem to be getting the notification. Or does this only work if the user is logged in? (mine aren't)

Answer (score 3):

Because the FBLikeActionController.h is a private header, you can get around that by listening to notification string:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(facebookLikeNotification:) name:@"FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification" object:nil];
```

And handling the notification using selectors.  I added lldb pragmas to suppress undefined selector warnings:

```
    - (void)facebookLikeNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
    SEL selector = @selector(objectIsLiked);
    if (notification.object && [notification.object respondsToSelector:selector]) {

        BOOL (*BOOLMsgSend)(id, SEL) = (typeof(BOOLMsgSend)) objc_msgSend;
        BOOL isLiked = BOOLMsgSend(notification.object, selector);
        DDLogDebug(@"is liked: %d",isLiked);

    }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Comment: FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification seems to be private. Witch version of sdk have you used?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the user changed the state of the button (i.e. if it was unliked and you like it), like it was my case, you can add `[likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourCallbackFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` and `yourCallbackFuntion:` will be called when the state of the like button changes.

I hope it helps

Comment: This is a good idea, but there's unless I'm missing something, there's nothing in the FBLikeControl (a UIControl subclass) to indicate whether the thing has been Liked or not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I cannot check whether it has been liked or not, but in my case I only needed to know if the user changed the state. Tim's answer is the correct one for his case

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside works better than UIControlEventValueChanged!

Answer (score 1):

A small gift for those who are facing this issue:

1. Import `#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKMacros.h>`
2. Define a nofitication key `FBSDK_EXTERN NSString *const FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification;`
3. Register a notification `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification) name:FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification object:nil];`

And a notification will be triggered whenever user make a change in the `LIKE` button (like or unlike).

Comment: Combining Kevin's method and Nikel Arteta's notification worked for me \m/