# How can i get the FBLikeController callback after like or dislike?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to integrate like button inside my application and i want to reward the user for the like with the code below.

How can i see if the user has liked or unliked the facebook page?..(i can add an target to button for UIEventValueChanged but it's a little bit ugly)

```
self.pageLikeControl.likeControlAuxiliaryPosition = FBLikeControlAuxiliaryPositionBottom;
self.pageLikeControl.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = FBLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
self.pageLikeControl.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/pages/JocTemp/379725092198791";
```

I saw on a similar question this answer [FBLikeControl callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236655/fblikecontrol-callback) but it doesn't find that class anymore...so i guess you can't

Comment: You shouldn't incentivize users like that. See section 4.5 of the Plaform Policy doc https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: And shouldn't means that your app would get disabled if you do it