# FBSDKLikeControl - How do I know the user liked the page or not?

Tags: ios, facebook

According to the Facebook documentation on [Like Button for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/like-button), I use `FBSDKLikeControl` to make a Like button for a Facebook page:

```
FBSDKLikeControl *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers";
likeButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:likeButton];
```

How can I know whether the user liked the page or not? Is there any callback using this `FBSDKLikeControl`?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236655/fblikecontrol-callback

Comment: I read this too, but nobody explained how to check in the callback function. Also, this callback is executed only when the Like button is clicked. My wish is to detect whether the user liked the page. If yes, skip showing the Like button & go to next step instead.

Comment: @Raptor, did you find any luck on this? I am going through exactly the same scenario.

Comment: No luck. I end up asking user to like the page, no matter he liked before or not. Not a very good user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_likes

Can't you just get this permission and check if your page is liked by the user and choose not to show the like control/button ?

So long as you do not do any like gating, you'll be fine (like gating is when you restrict access to the app itself, or some content within the app unless the user likes your page.)

Comment: In 2015, there was no such thing. I guess this can solve my old problem. Thanks.