# FBSDKLikeButton callback in swift facebook SDK v4.21.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk, notificationcenter

I'm coding in Swift 3 w/Facebook SDK 4.21.0, I'm trying to find a way to add a callback to FBSDKLikeButton so i know when the user actually liked / dislisked something.

I have tried both approaches found in this site:
- Add  a .valueChanged control event (not working)
- Add a NotificationCenter observer to FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification as described here: [FBLikeControl callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236655/fblikecontrol-callback/26256654#26256654)

What I'm doing:

```
                let like = FBSDKLikeControl()
                like.center = bcenter
                like.objectID = objectid

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                       selector: #selector(self.likeButtonChanged(_:)),
                                                       name: NSNotification.Name.init("FBLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification"),
                                                       object: nil)
```

However, my selector never gets calls no matter whether I like / unliked / cancel / throw the phone against the wall

Any pointers here?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working. I have tried the method below but I can't get the 'like' to report back to the app and the Facebook developers website only posts code in obj-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, did it by parsing the url in:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

}

```
fb{app-id}://bridge/like?version=web&bridge_args=%7B%22app_name%22%3A%22AAP-NAME%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22B0B73D93-6434-4FF0-A300-00B0A7E470BE%22%7D&method_results=%7B%22object_is_liked%22%3Afalse%2C%22like_count%22%3A5039330%2C%22like_count_string%22%3A%225M%22%2C%22social_sentence%22%3A%225M%20people%20like%20this.%22%2C%22completionGesture%22%3A%22unlike%22%2C%22didComplete%22%3A1%7
```

and setting a completion callback in the appdelegate that is set from the view that has the like button and then nillified once consumed